# Filesystemwatcher causing "Error too many changes at once in directory C:\"

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

Like a few others I'm getting the error "Error too many changes at once in directory C:\" from the filesystemwatcher when he does its job. Now if it is c:\ it is clear that there are many changes. BUT in this special case I set the following parameters:

```
Path = C:\
Filter = "test1.txt"
NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName
IncludeSubdirectories = true
```

I started the watcher and let it run without problems for 4 hours after which Í locked the pc and came back a short while later and suddenly had the error.

Now I'm wondering what could have caused the error in this case. Am I overlooking something important here? OR could it be taht the includesubdirectories parameter lets it check ALL subdirectories of c:\ and ignoring the filter of the single file that exists in C:\ ?

Comment: I am pretty sure the Filter is not ignored, but it works incrementally, meaning you tell it to look in `C:` and all its `Subdirectories` and monitor files that have the name `test1.txt`

Comment: why then does the error happen after a few hours and not immediately? (if it was immediately I would get it as there are just too many subdirectories the watcher looks into)

Comment: A Windows update is sufficient to kill your app.  Looking at *everything*, even the operating system directories, is of course not a great idea.

Comment: @HansPassant Good point there although should not the filter itself avoid the problem or am I misunderstanding then there how strong the filter is?

Comment: Looking at everything is not a good definition of a "strong filter".

Comment: I meant how strong the effect of "Filter = "test1.txt""  is with "strong filter"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the Buffer for changes - this helped me once.

But to look for every change at C:\ with subdirs can maybe cause a lot of workload..

[MSDN FileSystemWatcher.InternalBufferSize Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.internalbuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx)

**EDIT:**

The Filter gets only checked at the Raising-Method - so internally every change gets recognized by the class.

I took a look into the framework code
as you can see the main raising method .....

```
    private void NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(int action, string name)
    {
        if (this.MatchPattern(name))
        {
            switch (action)
            {
                case 1:
                    this.OnCreated(new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.Created, this.directory, name));
                    return;

                case 2:
                    this.OnDeleted(new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted, this.directory, name));
                    return;

                case 3:
                    this.OnChanged(new FileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes.Changed, this.directory, name));
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
```

is using this method: "this.MatchPattern(name)" - which look like this:

```
    private bool MatchPattern(string relativePath)
    {
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(relativePath);
        return ((fileName != null) && PatternMatcher.StrictMatchPattern(this.filter.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), fileName.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
    }
```

and as you can see - the filter get checked here - far to late to have suppressed load...
...So the only way is to increase the buffer size!

Comment: The changes are I think the mainquestion there. As specified (and cleared through a comment) it searches through subdirs.....filters the results for a specific .txt which is not modified in any way for hours then it throws the error. Thus the question is there is it really that much of a workload as the filter is only selecting a single file there?

Comment: Tnx so in total the exception is caused because for example an update runs and the filter though applied is applied way too late by the framework (ouch)

Comment: @Thomas Indeed. If you want to monitor file changes, do them in 1 specific folder with as few other files and directories as possible, preferably a subfolder of the program installation dir.

Comment: tnx there (wont be possible really for my concrete implenentation but your answer helped me find a workaround for the cause there tnx)