# VS 2019 crash: Oh wow message

Tags: crash, visual-studio-2019

When switching branches in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise 16.9.4 (using GIT), I sometimes get the following message, and VS crashes.  The message in the error is (unbelievably):

**oh wow: Systrem.IO.InternalBufferOverflowException:  Too many changes at once in (c:\my source code location)**

Has this been seen before?  I have searched and not found anything.  The solution is a database project.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519089/avoid-error-too-many-changes-at-once-in-directory ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995241/filesystemwatcher-causing-error-too-many-changes-at-once-in-directory-c ???

Comment: This is not a .NET programming question - it's caused by the VS IDE.   I don't think I can write code to fix this.

Comment: I agree but at least we know this is a thing.